I cant open a third window with PySimpleGUI
I found out that i have to do window3.read() in order to have it appear.
I can't create a third window. the code works without error but it doesn't display a window the code ends
Currently I'm trying to make it display a table of checkboxes for people to choose seating. i've tested if it simply didn't run. by putting print after it and it prints. I also tried to just have it display a simple text but that didn't work too.
Below is the code:
layout3 = [[sg.Text('Test')]
window3 = sg.Window('Choosing seats',layout3,element_justification='c')


Try to build a simple and executable script to demo how you open the third window.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Lots of Demo Programs for Multiple Windows are available as a starting point.
